# How to get RGB values of a pixel in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am getting started with JavaFX and basically what I am trying to implement is a Color Picker.
At first, I thought of having a rectangle with a LinearGradient that goes through all primary/secondary colors.

Looks like what I want, but the problem is that I can not get the RGB values at a given coordinate(x,y) in this Node.
I know you can do it through the fill property of any Shape IF it is a Color.

But Is there anyway to get the RGB values of anything inside a LinearGradient/Paint ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this [ColorPicker JavaFX example](http://developers.sun.com.cn/javafx/samples/EffectsPlayground/src/ColorPicker.fx.html) help?

```
[...]

function colorAtLocation(x:Integer, y:Integer) : Color {
    var bimg = iv.image.bufferedImage;
    if (x < 0 or x >= bimg.getWidth() or y < 0 or y >= bimg.getHeight()) {
        return null;
    }
    var rgb = bimg.getRGB(x, y);
    var r = Bits.bitAnd(Bits.shiftRight(rgb, 16), 0xff);
    var g = Bits.bitAnd(Bits.shiftRight(rgb,  8), 0xff);
    var b = Bits.bitAnd(Bits.shiftRight(rgb,  0), 0xff);
    Color.rgb(r, g, b)
}

function updateSelectedColor(e:MouseEvent) {
    var rgb = colorAtLocation(e.x, e.y);
    if (rgb != null) {
        picker.selectedColor = rgb;
    }
}

[...]
```

Comment: The image.bufferedImage no longer works with JavaFX 1.2.
One might be able to do this:
  var bimg = iv.image.platformImage as java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

Answer (score 0):

The `ColorPicker` JavaFX example starts with a `png` image that is loaded to an `image` that then populates the `ImageView`.

The question starts with a JavaFX `Rectangle` containing `LinearGradient`.

To get the rectangle contents into a buffered image, one can use the java.awt.Robot:

```
        var rectangle = new java.awt.Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
        var robot = new java.awt.Robot();
        var bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
```

where `rectangle` would be describe the coordinates of the JavaFX Rectangle containing the bits of interest.

The `robot.createScreenCapture` call has the gotcha that to do the screen capture, the screen has to be visible.  There should be a better of way to populate the buffered image but I've not yet encountered it.